# Dreckspatz und Schmutzfink

Tags: etymology

Einen schmutzigen Menschen nennt man Ferkel, Drecksau, Dreckschwein, Dreckspatz, Schmutz­fink, Drecksfink oder Mistfink.

Der Bezug auf Schweine ist mir klar, da Schweine sich gerne im Dreck suhlen (auch wenn sie dabei Körperpflege betreiben und nur matschig, nicht aber ungepflegt sind). Aber warum werden die beiden Vogelarten Finken und Spatzen als unsauber angesehen?

Woher kommt der Bezug zu Fink und Spatz in Dreckspatz und Schmutzfink?

Comment: Wobei ich ganz vorsichtig wäre, einen schmutzigen Menschen (im Sinne von verdreckt) eine Drecksau oder ein Dreckschwein zu nennen. Das ist nämlich eine schwere Beleidigung und wird im Allgemeinen *nicht* für jemanden verwendet, der sich schmutzig gemacht hat!

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar , äh ja, stimmt. Dreckspatz kann ja noch süß gemeint sein, Drecksau sicher nicht.

Comment: @Iris: Kommt drauf an, mit wem Du Sex hast.  Woody Allen sagt, Sex muss nichts schmutziges sein, nur wenn man 's richtig macht. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Antwort darauf findest Du in [diesem Wikipedia- Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbad) zum Thema "Sandbad".

Spatzen (oder auch Haussperlinge) und Finken (ebenfalls zur Familie der Sperlingsvögel gehörig) gehören demnach zu den wenigen Vogelarten, die sich im Sand "baden". Dabei legen Sie sich mit dem Bauch in eine Sandkuhle und wirbeln dann Staub auf, der sich auf Ihr Gefieder legt.

Dieses Ritual dient der Reinigung des Gefieders.
Genaueres kannst Du im verlinkten Artikel nachlesen.

Aber da kommt der Begriff des "Dreckspatz" her.

In [diesem Artikel](http://etymologie.tantalosz.de/d.php) ist die etymlologische Wortherkunft auch nochmal genau so erklärt (nach Dreckspatz suchen)

Comment: Und weil ein Bild, zumal 100e bewegt, mehr sagt als Worte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOuB08ohBrk ;)

Answer (score -3):

Ihr macht es euch zu leicht Freunde.
Dreckspatz und Schmutzfink haben eine ähnliche, jedoch unterschiedliche Bedeutung:
Schmutzfink: jemand, der etwas schmutzig macht;
Dreckspatz: jemand, der sich schmutzig gemacht hat.

Damit es in der metaphorischen Übertragung einen solchen radikalen Unterschied gibt, muss es auch im Verhalten der beiden Vogelarten einen Unterschied geben.

Um es zu verdeutlichen, aus der soeben gemachten Erfahrung:

Im Sandbad, das wir neben der Vogeltränke im Garten eingerichtet haben, wühlen sich die Spatzen. Der Fink aber hat sich oben of dem First des Hauses postiert, und kackt uns von da oben die Marquise voll.

Comment: Und der Unterschied wäre...? Im Moment ist Dein Post leider eher ein Kommentar, als eine eigenständige Antwort. Wäre schön, wenn Du es entsprechend editieren und ergänzen könntest...

Comment: Hast du einen Beleg zu dieser Behauptung. Ich habe Finken bisher nicht als belästigende Tiere wahrgenommen. Anhand dieser Begründung würde ich Schutztauben erwarten ;)